# How to paginate based on number of elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have certian images and intend to paginate according to its number. Like I want 9 images (3 rows X 3 columns) in one 1st page 9 images in another and so on. So how could that be done?

```
const data = [
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
}));

const useStyles3 = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes3 = useStyles3();
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={4}>
            {data.map((dataNew) => (
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <img src={dataNew.img} height="30px" />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      <div className={classes3.root}>
        <Pagination count={10} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

What could be the appropriate solution for images to render with pagination?

Here is the codesanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3s9if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain state to achieve this

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const data = [
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  },
  {
    img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/21/13/00/rose-165819__340.jpg"
  }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
}));

const useStyles3 = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes3 = useStyles3();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={4}>
            {data.slice((currentPage - 1) * 9, currentPage * 9).map((dataNew) => (
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <img src={dataNew.img} height="30px" />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      <div className={classes3.root}>
        <Pagination count={Math.ceil(data.length / 9)} onChange={(event, value) => setCurrentPage(value)} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```